# Failed to restart postgresql.service: Unit postgresql.service is masked

Tags: postgresql

How can I solve this? (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)

```
sudo service postgresql restart 
Failed to restart postgresql.service: Unit postgresql.service is masked.
```

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Comment: I solved the problem by "apt-get install".   
Although I get from answer a more elegant way to fix it  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.04 and earlier used upstart. Upstart uses the `service` command to handle services. As of 16.04 Ubuntu is using systemd. Any service commands you use get remapped to `systemctl` commands. Systemd provides more functionality than upstart, including the ability to mask a service so that it cannot be started. Masking a service (from what I understand) essentially symlinks it to /dev/null. You should be able to unmask and restart the service with the following commands.

```
systemctl unmask postgresql
systemctl restart postgresql
```

Comment: If postgresql does not work try using postgresql.service

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Docker. then make sure the container is running.
do that by typing Docker ps. if the container is missing but appears in Docker ps -a then just use Docker start